# Access command line arguments as bytes in python3

Tags: python-3.x, binary-data, argv

Is it possible to access the raw argv elements binary content ?

```
$ python3 -c'import sys;print(sys.argv);' `echo -ne "\xff\x80\x00\xff"`
['-c', '\udcff\udc80\udcff']
```

Comment: Please note that this is not a filename encoding issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557830/command-line-arguments-as-bytes-instead-of-strings-in-python3 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981594/sys-argv-as-bytes-in-python-3k i'm not having any text encoding issue. It's not about text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the argv contant as bytes as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
arg1_bytes = sys.argv[1].encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding(), 'surrogateescape')
```

Source: [PEP 383 - Non-decodable Bytes in System Character Interfaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/), via [answer on "Command-line arguments as bytes instead of strings in python3"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557893/1953103); see also [answer on "sys.argv as bytes in Python 3k"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077803/1953103)