# How to retrieve argv ORIGINAL byte data in Py3?

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I have already seen [Access command line arguments as bytes in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27704783/1874170); this does not answer my question.

**For instance,** bytes such as `\xff` do not get passed through when `sys.getfilesystemencoding()=='utf-8'`, and byte sequences such as `\xe2\x8d\xaa` (the UTF-8 representation of U+236A) do not get through if I attempt to decode `sys.argv` as `latin-1`.

Therefore, I ask:

What do I need to do to, when my program is passed *exactly* the following through the execution ABI:

```c
char argv[] = {
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
     0xff, // junk "canary" byte
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    0xe2, 0x98, 0xba, // U+236A
    ' ',
    '\0'
};
```

deduce

```py
assert argv == b'123\xffABC\xe2\x98\xba\x20'
```

in Python 3? (though, a bilingual solution would be preferred)

---

*In*valid results include:

- `b'123\xc3\xbfABC\xe2\x98\xba\x20'`
- `codec can't encode character '\u236a' in position 7: ordinal not in range(256)`
- `b'123\xffABC\x20'`
- `b'123ABC\xe2\x98\xba\x20'`
- `b'123ABC\xe2\x98\xba'`

Before erroneously marking this question as a "duplicate", please see which of the invalid results your proposed duplicate returns.

I am specifically attempting to retrieve the actual **bytes** that were originally passed to the python script — no matter how arbitrary they are.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Python Issue #8776](https://bugs.python.org/issue8776), although their "workaround" returns `b'\xc3\xbf` when `0xFF` was one of the original `argv` bytes, which is **objectively incorrect**.

Comment: If you need to "guess" the proper encoding, you can use [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) library. But it is imposible to be 100% sure it will work all the times: a simple reason for that is that you can create your own encoding system.

Comment: @OwlMax Well, no matter whether I "guess" `utf-8` OR `iso-8859-1`, none of these return the desired result, which is the problem.

Comment: Promising: `from codecs import register_error;register_error('utf-8', lambda e:(e.object[e.start:e.end].encode('utf-8'),e.end))`, although I need to do more testing to see how to implement it

Comment: Interesting question. POSIX doesn't requires argv to be a string. It could be just binary (without two consecutive zero bytes). According python sources, `sys.argv` is internally converted, so not usable for such task. I do no find other mathod to get argv as bytes on python libraries.

Comment: As someone who's normally a big fan of Python 3 and the way they've improved string handling, it's kind of shocking to see that P2 has the ability to perform a technical feat that's *physically* not reliably achievable by P3! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For non-edge-cases:

If `argv` is anything *approximating* reasonable command-line arguments, the following should be serviceable (and the most idiomatic way to access them, to boot):

```
list(map(os.fsencode, sys.argv))
```

(h/t vstinner from the below discussion)

## For edge-cases: impossible+`wontfix`

See the discussion at https://bugs.python.org/issue8776

or, for the lazy-but-curious, the relevant excerpts (emphasis+formatting added):

> [msg106172]
>
> …`Py_Main` expects `wchar_t*`, so **no byte-oriented representation of the
>   command line is readily available.**
>
> [-Martin v. Löwis]

> [msg217416]
>
> Today I regret `os.environb` (I added it). If I remember correctly, `os.environb` was added before the PEP 383 (`surrogateescape`). This PEP makes `os.environb` almost useless. In Python 3, Unicode is the natural choice, and thanks to the PEP 383, it's still possible to use any "raw bytes".
>
> `argvb` can be computed in one line: `list(map(os.fsencode, sys.argv))`.
>
> **I now suggest to close [Bytes version of sys.argv] as wontfix.**
>
> [-STINNER Victor]

while his "one line" fails on edge cases (such as where an element of the true `argv` contains a bytestring such as `0x313233c3bf414243c3a2c298c2ba00`), it works in the proverbial 99.9% of use-cases.